# Obtain a particular URL from a large string

Tags: c#

I have some exported performance data from Chrome in C# and it contains a large amount of URL's.  I want one specifically and only the first occurance of it.  Actually could be any as it's repeated a number of times, however if I have a string of various garbage and URL's mixed in, how would I find the one that starts with https and ends in mpa?

So it would be like https://thisisaurl.com/2020/11/20/14243324324/324234/test.mpa  Note everything between the https and mpa could be different.  Actually the thisisaurl.com will probably stay the same but can't be sure right now.  Just know the URL would end in mpa.

I've been playing with something like this:

```
var linkParser = new Regex(@"\b(?:https?://|mpa\.)\S+\b", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
foreach (Match m in linkParser.Matches(logs[i].Message))
  Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
```

But wasn't giving me what I'm looking for.  Just some other URL starting with https.  Appreciate any help.

Also example below:

```
{"columnNumber":104001,"functionName":"","lineNumber":1,"scriptId":"9","url":"https://www.blabla.com/assets/build/js/show/videoTop-b8f5d35a3719d4f31aee.min.js"},{"columnNumber":82859,"functionName":"makeRequestStandard","lineNumber":427,"scriptId":"31","url":"https://tags.blabla2.com/utag/i/comsite/prod/utag.js"},{"columnNumber":82357,"functionName":"makeRequest","lineNumber":427,"scriptId":"31","url":"https://tags.blabla2.com/utag/i/comsite/prod/utag.js"},{"columnNumber":168917,"functionName":"request","lineNumber":427,"scriptId":"31","url":"https://tags.blabla2.com/utag/i/comsite/prod/utag.js"},{"columnNumber":162205,"functionName":"send","lineNumber":427,"scriptId":"31","url":"https://tags.blabla2.com/utag/i/comsite/prod/utag.js"},{"columnNumber":132652,"functionName":"postHeartbeat","lineNumber":427,"scriptId":"31","url":"https://tags.blabla2.com/utag/i/comsite/prod/utag.js"},{"columnNumber":131860,"functionName":"sendHeartbeat","lineNumber":427,"scriptId":"31","url":"https://tags.blabla2.com/utag/i/comsite/prod/utag.js"},{"hasPostData":true,"headers":{"Content-Type":"application/json","Referer":"https://www.bla.com/info/me/a4Af8ptKlr5gthauHnde5C9JdeJcNnWa","User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0
https://blabla3.bla.com/2020/11/20/1822084675943/383378/value.mpa\",\":null,\"evs\":[{\"name\":\"\",\"attr\":
```

So in the case of above want

```
https://blabla3.bla.com/2020/11/20/1822084675943/383378/value.mpa
```

Note the string contains a lot more than above, that's just a middle snippet.

Comment: Have you tried string's StartsWith or EndsWith methods? Or even the Uri class scheme and segments properties?

Comment: Doesn't StartsWith and EndsWith just tell you if the string as a whole starts with something and ends with something? I updated my post above with some additional text in the hope it will show more detail.   Also based on my original post, I'm almost thinking it would have to first find a reference to ".mpa" and then search backwards for there for the first instance of https

Answer (score 0):

You had the right idea using a regular expression, you just need to tweak it some. For one, you should be escaping the / after https. I was able to match the string you were looking for with a quick and dirty regex of `https:\/\/[^\s]+[\w].mpa` It will match the characters `https:` literally, `\/` will match the character `/` literally, `[^\s]+` will match a non whitespace character multiple times (`^` is a negation, `\s` short for whitespace characters), `\w` will match a word character (i.e. value in value.mpa), and `.mpa` will match those characters literally. You can tweak it as needed for case insensitivity or other needs